# How to sum if values from another column match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I would like to do is if two numbers from column B match I would like to add the values from column G.
Basically this is a trade sheet, each selection will have a + and - figure so I need the final figure to tell me if it was a + trade or a - one.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify where you want the formula/result and one example of what such result will be?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I thought I might not make it clear. 
I will create an additional column for the result. I notice I didn't include two matching selection_ids with figures in the picture.

For example in column B each selection id (28654373 for example) will have minimum 2 entries with there profit figure in column G. I need to sum these.

So selection id 43121960 has a profit of 3.64 in G column, further down (out of picture) there is another entry for 43121960 saying a profit of -3.42 so in the new column it would have the figure 0.22. 
I hope I've explained it a bit better.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing information.

Comment: [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)?

Comment: You want a running total? You'll need to anchor the first part of the cell reference, I don;t know if this is plays nicely with excel tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show summed net result of trade for row than your answer is pretty simple:

```
=SUMIF(B:B;B2;G:G)
```

Or in your situation, as you are using a tabled range, you can alternatively use table references like:

```
=SUMIF([selection_id];[@[selection_id]];[profit])
```

Now, if you want it to have it summing up with each new row only the previous results (running total), you are limited to classic references only and you need to anchor (with $) the first cells in search range and sum range. Enter this formula in H2 cell (and then copy it to other cells if it won't autofill for some reason):

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B2;B2;G$2:G2)
```